# About proving independent random variable of the continuous type

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

> Problem: Let X and Y be independent random variables of the continuous type. Then X and.Y have the joint PDF: $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x) f_Y(y)$. Prove that events ${a \leq X \leq b}$ and ${c \leq Y \leq d}$ are independent for any numbers $a,b,c,d$.

My answer: Since it has the joint PDF:$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x) f_Y(y)$, and since X and Y are independent if and only if $f_{X,Y}(x,y)= f_X(x) f_Y(y)$, it is clear that $\int_{a}^b \int_{c}^d f_{X,Y}(x,y) dy dx=\int_{a}^b f_X(x) dx \int_{c}^d f_Y(y) dy $

> Question: Can I leave like that?

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to prove with your proof. What means $X$ and $Y$ are independent ?

Comment: @Surb How about my new edit?

Comment: @neveryield The integral equation is not an equality because the random variables are independent, it is an equality because the joint pdf is a separable product, and integration is a linear operation.$$\small\begin{align}\int_a^b\int_c^d f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x&=\int_a^b\int_c^d f_{X}(x)\,f_{Y}(y)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\\&=\int_a^bf_X(x)\int_c^d f_{Y}(y)\,\mathrm d y\,\,\mathrm d x\\&=\int_a^bf_X(x)\,\mathrm d x\cdot \int_c^d f_{Y}(y)\,\mathrm d y\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question: Can I leave like that?

That looks sufficiently convincing. Though it might be advisable to identify that those integrals do represent : $$\mathsf P(a\leqslant X \leqslant b\cap c\leqslant Y\leqslant  d)=\mathsf P(a\leqslant X\leqslant b)~\mathsf P(c\leqslant Y\leqslant d)$$